# Enet.c library not working correctly on mips system

Tags: c, mips, enet

I'm trying to create a function which uses enet to send some data, but first I wanted to make sure the example in [here](https://github.com/zpl-c/enet) works correctly on the mips system.

I tested the example on Ubuntu and Mac and it works perfectly fine, but when I test it on the mips system it always fails to create the host, which is always created without any trouble on the other systems I tested. Do someone here knows what might be happening? Someone told me that it might be a problem with the libenet.so file, but since it works with the enet_initialize function, I think it might be something else.

This is my code if someone wants to check it out:

```
#define ENET_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <enet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (enet_initialize () != 0) {
        printf("An error occurred while initializing ENet.\n");
        return 1;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Welcome to enet! :D\n");
    }

    //Client side
    ENetHost* client = { 0 };
    client = enet_host_create(NULL /* create a client host */,
                              1 /* only allow 1 outgoing connection */,
                              2 /* allow up 2 channels to be used, 0 and 1 */,
                              0 /* assume any amount of incoming bandwidth */,
                              0 /* assume any amount of outgoing bandwidth */);
    if (client == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "An error occurred while trying to create an ENet client host.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    else {
        printf("Client created successfully! :D\n");
    }

    enet_host_destroy(server);
    enet_deinitialize();
    return 0; 
}
```

And my output is the messages:
Welcome to enet! :D
An error occurred while trying to create an ENet client host.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it and stepping into the `enet_host_create` function to see where it's failing. It looks like the source code for that function is in the [header file](https://github.com/zpl-c/enet/blob/0bbff4db335ebffd6ce85e3489f356ca0266d16c/include/enet.h#L4392).

If you're not able to debug and step through it, you could temporarily modify the header file to add additional logging.

Some potential reasons it's failing:

- `peerCount > ENET_PROTOCOL_MAXIMUM_PEER_ID`
- `enet_malloc` malloc fails to allocate memory
- `net_socket_create(ENET_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM) == ENET_SOCKET_NULL`

I'm thinking that it's probably not an issue with the `peerCount` because the default `ENET_PROTOCOL_MAXIMUM_PEER_ID` is `0xFFF` and you're passing `1`.

It may be an issue with `enet_malloc` or `net_socket_create`. By default `enet_malloc` is just the regular `malloc` from stdlib, which I'm guessing is what you're using since you're not initializing with `enet_initialize_with_callbacks`. And `enet_socket_create` just calls the `socket` system call:

```c
ENetSocket enet_socket_create(ENetSocketType type) {
    return socket(PF_INET6, type == ENET_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM ? SOCK_DGRAM : SOCK_STREAM, 0);
}
```

I would make sure your platform's `malloc` and `socket` implementations are working as expected.